# Is there a way to copy a line without the indentation in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I just want to know if there is a short cut to copy the text line without the indent part.

Thanks!

Comment: If you found an answer to your question helpful, do not only mark it as accepted answer, but consider upvoting it, too.

Comment: I have done it, but my reputation does not allow to make it public!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the cursor is at the end of the line:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> works.

If your cursor is anywhere in the line, hit <kbd>End</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

It should work out-of-the-box by pressing Ctrl+C (at least it does in my VSCodium instance), but in contrast to, e.g. IntelliJ IDEA, it does not select the the line visually in the editor.